# Timestamp String in Zulu Format To Datetime

Tags: pandas

I am dealing with timestamps that, according to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search#Activity.FIELDS.activity_time), are:

> A timestamp in RFC3339 UTC "Zulu" format, accurate to nanoseconds. Example: "2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z".

So, for example, if the string is `'2019-11-06T06:24:42.558008Z'`, then `pd.to_datetime('2019-11-06T06:24:42.558008Z',infer_datetime_format=True)` works and returns `Timestamp('2019-11-06 06:24:42.558008')`.

However, letting Pandas infer the format is slow, and I have many rows of data. What would I pass the `format` parameter to help speed up the processing?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('2019-11-06T06:24:42.558008Z')` seems to run fine?

Comment: Actually that is a format defined in the widely used [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. [RFC 3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339) is but a mere self-declared “profile” of ISO 8601, and violates important rules. I suggest avoiding RFC 3339 and sticking to ISO 8601. The “Zulu” refers to the military and aviation tradition of using the letter `Z` as an abbreviation for an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `utc=True` + [tz_convert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html):

```
import pandas as pd

utc = pd.to_datetime('2019-11-06T06:24:42.558008Z', utc=True).tz_convert(None)
inferred = pd.to_datetime('2019-11-06T06:24:42.558008Z', infer_datetime_format=True)

print(utc == inferred)
```

**Output**

```
True
```

From the documentation on `tz_convert`:

> A tz of None will convert to UTC and remove the timezone information.

Note that only doing:

```
utc = pd.to_datetime('2019-11-06T06:24:42.558008Z', utc=True)  # or pd.to_datetime('2019-11-06T06:24:42.558008Z')
```

throws a TypeError exception when comparing with `inferred`:

> TypeError: Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware timestamps

Comment: ahhh -- interesting. so passing `None` to `tz_convert` works because Zulu essentially has no timezone offest?

Comment: @measureallthethings None remove timezone information.