# pandas calculate time difference to now

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, subset

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with a time column containing datetime values. I now want to filter the dataframe to show rows with time values lying in  the next 15 minutes.

So first I try to simply subtract the current time from the datetimes.

```
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time) 
print(df.Time  - pd.to_datetime("today"))
```

But got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot subtract tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects
```

I tried to remove the tz-awareness with `.replace(tzinfo=None)` but it was not working. In the end I am looking for a command like this (assuming the difference of two datetimes in is minutes):

```
df.loc[df.Time - pd.to_datetime("today") < 15]
```

Comment: how does `df.Time` look like? What's the time zone?

Comment: @jezrael: the linked dupe uses native Python datetime, I don't think that is necessary here. OP can set a tz for pd.Timestamp or localize the input to None for example and use pd only ;-)

Comment: @FObersteiner - like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58843039/2901002) ?

Comment: @FObersteiner - If you think both dupes are not usable, I can reopen question. Then please create answer.

Comment: @jezrael I'm not totally sure what is best here, not knowing what tz the input is in and what OP means by "now" (local time? UTC?). I've added the pd equivalent to the first dupe ("Compare timestamp with datetime") as a comment.

Comment: @FObersteiner - You can create answer, in my opinion.

Comment: The links answered my question. Thanks